# The name 'DockingManager" does not exist in namespace http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/avalondock

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, avalondock, xceed

In a C# WPF project, I added Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock into References. In xaml file, I have

```
xmlns:xcad="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/avalondock"
...
<xcad:DockingManager x:Name="DockMangager" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
</xcad:DockingManager>
```

Could someone help? Thank you!

Comment: When do you get the error? when compiling? when running? :)

Comment: @Jauch it looks like a warning. But the main problem is that there is no auto-complete

Comment: why I need to add <xcad:  everytime to access DockingManager ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a security problem of the dll when downloaded from the internet.

- Go to the `Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.dll` file in Windows explorer
- Open "Properties"
- On the bottom of the dialog there is a warning under "Security"
- Click on "Unblock"
- Rebuild the project

You can also read this: 
http://www.kodyaz.com/visual-studio/unblock-assembly-file-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx

Comment: in my case i added the xml namespace (i.e xmlns:ad <<-- )with Docking manager references. When I did, it solved the problem (i.e <ad:DockingManager )

Answer (score 0):

Just had this happen to me.  Mine were not blocked.  My references had a yellow warning by them.  I just added the Xceed DLLs again, rebuilt, and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Add the reference to the project again and the error will go away.
it is always good after adding references to clear the recent to make sure that unchecked references are not being removed.